# Trouble with static methods calling eachother c#

Tags: c#, static-methods

I'm trying to replace all MessageBox.Show calls in my applicaiton so I've created a static MsgBox class with two methods defined below:

(one)

```
public static MessageBoxResult Show(Window owner, string messageBoxText, string caption = "",
                                            MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OK,
                                            MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.None,
                                            MessageBoxResult defaultResult = MessageBoxResult.None)
```

and this one which calls the other

(two)

```
public static MessageBoxResult Show(string messageBoxText, string caption = "",
                                            MessageBoxButton button = MessageBoxButton.OK,
                                            MessageBoxImage icon = MessageBoxImage.None,
                                            MessageBoxResult defaultResult = MessageBoxResult.None)

{

    return Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, messageBoxText, caption, button, icon, defaultResult);
}
```

So the issue is if I call the first one directly, no problems, everything works. But if I call the second one nothing happens.

Is there something I'm not understanding about how this all works?

Comment: How are you calling the second one? EDIT: And the first one.

Comment: MsgBox.Show("Message", "Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

Comment: Sorry, Skinner, and how are you calling the first one as well? Also, can you reproduce this in a new/blank project? (and if so, provide us with code to reproduce it ourselves?)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair
I'm never calling the first one directly. When I was having trouble with:

MsgBox.Show("Message", "Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information); 

I just added a reference to the window and it works:

MsgBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "Message", "Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

Which is funny because it's exactly what method 2 is doing.

Edit: I'll try and throw a project together

Comment: Could it be the reference to Application.Current from a static context? You could try making #2 non-static to test.

Comment: @Dan Whether the method is static or not wouldn't affect that property.

Comment: @Skinner927: You didn't post the method body to your first `Show` method, but I'm _guessing_ it's essentially `return MessageBox.Show(owner, messageBoxText, caption, button, icon, defaultResult);`?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair the body of the first method consists of switch statements that switch the MessageBox parameters to TasskDialog params and displays a TaskDialog: [rundown](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/71793/windows-7-task-dialogs/).

Comment: @Dan I think you've hit the nail on the head. I've made a test application and it seems I've overlooked that fact that I can't resolve the main window from a background thread (or so it seems?).

Comment: @Skinner927: No, I don't think you can. See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3e6eb7cd-4277-443b-a852-0da4b37db2de/systemapplicationcurrentmainwindow-crashes-in-other-threads (I thought about this too, but wrongly _assumed_ that you already had _working_ code from where you were calling it. That is, you already had it working, then switched the call up without any real changes. Woops!)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Is there a proper way that you know of to resolve the main window or should I just store a reference?

Answer (score 3):

The .Show overloaded method is used to display whatever type of MessageBox you desire.
You are returning a .Show which is not being applied to any MessageBox, so you need to take this returned value and use it like `MessageBox.Show(whateverReturned)`

Comment: I read this answer and feel it could be misinterpreted (it's not clear). But -- In other words, your second method needs to call `MessageBox.Show`, your first method needs to call `Show()`. In your code above, nowhere is `MessageBox.Show()` ever being called. Or vice-versa - you didn't include the method body of the first example.

Comment: Thanks Steve! :) New guy here! Hard part is getting the answer from my head into actual words, but yes I think the confusion was in thinking that some new code could just be added and that it would be automatically called.

Comment: I never call MessageBox.show anywhere, this class is trying to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the answer is that I was trying to get the MainWindow from a background thread which isn't allowed.

I've changed the second methods code to this:

```
Window mainWindow = null;
UiDispatcher.Invoke(delegate { mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow; }, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
return Show(mainWindow, messageBoxText, caption, button, icon, defaultResult);
```

Thanks again @Dan and @ChrisSinclair for walking me through it!